# Why is there such a big difference between request time and query time with a axios ajax request to laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I just wonder. I'm looking at my laravel site with lighthouse ans is see a First contentfull paint of 7 seconds and i'm wondering why, my javascript is not more the 500K (app.js 300K) total, is that a lot? I'm using laravel/Inertia/Vue. It looks as if the page with the the most javascript is the slowest but that also has the most ajax calls. I'm looking at the second. I installed laravel telescope and i noticed the following. I have a very simple request to:

```
App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index
```

Which triggers:

```
public function index(Balance $balance)
{
    return Category::where('balance_id', $balance->id)->get();
}
```

Very basic nothing fancy. The following queries are triggered:

```
update `sessions` set `payload` =...    2.87ms  
select * from `categories` where `balance_id` = 1   1.32ms  
select * from `balances` where `balances`.`user_id` = 1 and `balances`.`user_id` is not null limit 1    8.88ms  
select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1    4.15ms  
select * from `balances` where `id` = '1' limit 1   1.77ms  
select * from `sessions` where `id` = '7iGBQdBdKA8KrTvJOqBfLhmX' limit 1    9.95ms
```

Total query time is 28ms but the request time is 339ms. Anyone have an idea as to where the difference comes from?

Comment: There's way too many things that can affect your page speed and disclosing your entire codebase for reproducing isn't viable nor relevant for a Q&A platform like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is this production? dev? 1 thing  experience with is in dev with dockerzied laravel app in windows. Which makes it very slow. Just my 2 cents

Comment: I run linux as a dev and production environment. There are small differences but not so much as that production solves the problem. But this is dev.

Comment: Enabling http2 support on my server solved 90% of the problem